# How do I limit Explorer File Search to file names and directory names only? Deactivating "Search in file contents" does not work

Tags: windows-10, file-search

In Windows 10, when I enter "wheel", it finds files which are not related to my search.
This does not make sense to me, and I don't want that.

I have deactived the search option "Search in file contents".

However, this does not work.
Here is a screenshot of the results.

How can I make it so that it finds only those file which include my search term in their file name without writing any fancy search string like exact:="*wheel*" or so.

Also, I am not interested in the directory names.
So if a file path is that...

c:\wheels\somefile.txt

... then it should not show this.
It should however show the directory "c:\wheels".

I could swear that there was a time when Windows worked like that somewhen...

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: When you changed the search options, did you rebuild the index?  You must do that.

Comment: You have to get "fancy" enough to type `name:wheel`

Comment: In my opinion the Windows built-in search is not very good especially when searching for file names. If you often search for files by name I recommend to take a look onto [Search Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/) which directly uses the NTFS file-system data as search index so it can search for all files without lengthy index creation.

Comment: @Robert You have helped me so much! I thought I was just stupid. "Everything" is so good, just amazing. Thank you! Best recommendation ever.